# Algorithm to place x items equidistantly on an n by m wrapping grid

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm creating a simple grid based browser game where I would like to place players and target cells (think king-of-the-hill) equidistantly. Ideally this would be done in such a way that each player would also be equally distant from the nearest target cell.

Here are the requirements:

- The game needs to support **2 to 20 players**.
- The `n` by `m` grid can be **any size**, but the more 'square-like' the better. (The principle behind 'square-like' is to reduce the maximum required distance to travel across the grid - keep things more accessible)
- The number of target cells is flexible.
- Each player should have equal access to the same number of targets.
- The **minimum** distance between any player or target and any other player or target is **4**.

Note that each cell has **8** immediate neighbors (yes diagonals count as a distance of **1**), and ***edges wrap***. Meaning those at the bottom are logically adjacent to those at the top, and same for left/right.

I've been trying to think of a good algorithm to **place players and targets in varying distributions** without having to create a specific pre-determined grid for each number of players. I discovered [k-means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) and [Lloyd's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd%27s_algorithm), but I'm not very familiar with them, and don't really know how to apply them to this specific case, particularly since the number of target cells is flexible, which I would think should simplify the solution a bit.

Here's a snippet of vastly simplified code creating a pre-determined 6 player grid, just to show the essence of what I'm aiming for:

```js
var cellSize = 20;
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

function Cell(x, y) {
  this.x = x * cellSize + cellSize / 2;
  this.y = y * cellSize + cellSize / 2;
  this.id = x + '-' + y;
  this.neighbors = [];
  this.type = null;
}

Cell.prototype.draw = function() {
  var color = '#ffffff';
  if (this.type === 'base') {
    color = '#0000ff';
  } else if (this.type === 'target') {
    color = '#ff0000';
  }
  var d = cellSize / 2;
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(this.x - d, this.y - d, this.x + d, this.y + d);
  ctx.rect(this.x - d, this.y - d, this.x + d, this.y + d);
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.stroke();
};

// Pre-set player and target cells for 6 players as an example
var playerCells = ['0-0', '8-0', '16-0', '0-8', '8-8', '16-8'];
var targetCells = ['4-4', '12-4', '20-4', '4-12', '12-12', '20-12'];
var n = 24;
var m = 16;
canvas.width = n * cellSize + 6;
canvas.height = m * cellSize + 6;

var cellList = [];

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    var cell = new Cell(i, j);
    if (playerCells.indexOf(cell.id) > -1) {
      cell.type = 'base';
    } else if (targetCells.indexOf(cell.id) > -1) {
      cell.type = 'target';
    }
    cellList.push(cell);
  }
}

// Give each cell a list of it's neighbors so we know where things can move
for (var i = 0; i < cellList.length; i++) {
  var cell = cellList[i];
  var neighbors = [];

  // Get the cell indices around the current cell
  var cx = [cell.x - 1, cell.x, cell.x + 1];
  var cy = [cell.y - 1, cell.y, cell.y + 1];
  var ci, cj;

  for (ci = 0; ci < 3; ci++) {
    if (cx[ci] < 0) {
      cx[ci] = n - 1;
    }
    if (cx[ci] >= n) {
      cx[ci] = 0;
    }
    if (cy[ci] < 0) {
      cy[ci] = m - 1;
    }
    if (cy[ci] >= m) {
      cy[ci] = 0;
    }
  }
  for (ci = 0; ci < 3; ci++) {
    for (cj = 0; cj < 3; cj++) {
      // Skip the current node since we don't need to link it to itself
      if (cellList[n * ci + cj] === cell) {
        continue;
      }
      neighbors.push(cellList[n * ci + cj]);
    }
  }
}

drawGrid();

function drawGrid() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for (var i = 0; i < cellList.length; i++) {
    cellList[i].draw();
  }
}
```

It creates a grid that looks like this:
[image: Grid Example]

Where blue cells are players and red cells are targets.

### Does anyone have any suggestions for how to go about this?

Links to helpful material would be greatly appreciated.

### Are there any gurus out there who can drum up an awesome placement algorithm which satisfies all of the above conditions?

It would be **AMAZING** if the solution also allows the number of target cells and/or minimum distance to be configurable for **any** number of players and still satisfies all of the conditions, although that's not strictly necessary.

## EDIT

After some other game design considerations, I changed the minimum distance between player & target to **4** instead of **2**. The text, code, and image above have been changed accordingly. At the time of this edit, no solutions were constrained by that requirement, so it shouldn't affect anything.

## EDIT 2

If you are proposing a solution, please provide JavaScript code (or at least pseudo-code) outlining the detailed steps of your solution. Also please explain how the solution meets the requirements. Thank you!

Comment: You must have missed the part where I said the edges **wrap**. So each of them have equal access to four targets.

Comment: Please say more about the grid size - how is that determined; e.g., by in-game results, by player settings, arbitrarily by the programmer? For example, if the grid size is huge, one seemingly easy solution would be to have players far from one another but close to their target/s. Is it important to have shared targets?

Comment: The grid size should be whatever works best for the placement of players. It is not predefined and would be an output of the algorithm. Making a huge grid where players are all just close to a single target, may seem like an easy solution, but not when you realize that even then, you'd have to make sure each player had equal access to the same number of targets - even when those targets are far away.

Comment: _Your conditions (strict)_, _varying distribution_, _useful performance_ - I suspect you'll have to choose 2 out of these 3 things. I might be too stupid, but the only algorithms I can think of to generate a naturally-looking distribution while strictly assuring fairness would run in exponential time, and thus are quite useless. As an alternative, you could relax the equal access rule, e.g. that each player has the same distance to their closest target.

Comment: @CedricReichenbach None of my requirements mention performance. I never said these maps had to be generated at run-time. If you have a solution that does not strictly meet one of the requirements (like equal access), I would still like to see it. A solution that meets all conditions would be better of course, but if none of the provided solutions meet all of them, then the next best thing will be accepted.

Comment: The simplest solution fitting your bullet points would be to have two circular arrangements (interchangeably) of players and targets (i.e. on average every player has the same access to targets) - in addition to your points, please define if you prefer more uniform player distribution over target distribution or vice versa. Maybe add an example of 3 players and 2 or 4 targets respectively. Are you interested in solutions where #targets is restricted to a (parameterisable) function of #players?

Comment: You are asking for essentially a complete implementation of a complex piece of code, rather than the intended purpose of this site which is to help you learn.  I'll therefore limit myself to a comment about how you can do this.  One good way to solve this is to relax your conditions to merely look for "good enough" solutions, and then use simulated annealing to produce solutions.  See http://ai-maker.com/the-simulated-annealing-algorithm/ for a basic introduction to that and a code sample in JavaScript.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by, "Each player should have equal access to the same number of targets" ? Does it mean the targets closest to any one player are also equidistant from that player? Or perhaps that the target-distance-configuration for each player is the same (e.g., each player has 2 accessible targets at distances 5 & 6)? Also, how do you measure "access" in 2D, is it Manhattan or Euclidean distance (and if the latter, then from/to which exact points on the cells)?

Comment: @גלעדברקן the idea behind that statement is that no player should have a significant advantage over the others. Ideally, if you listed the distances from each player to targets 1-n, each list should be permutations of each other (same numbers, differing order) to be equally fair, although I realize that reduces variability, so giving up some fairness for variability is ok. In this specific case, "access" means **the number of moves it takes to get from cell a to cell b**, where it is 1 move from each cell to each neighboring cell, so neither of those methods are completely accurate.

Comment: @NanoWizard relaxing the fairness might not be as much fun to try and solve :)

Comment: A simple solution is to take your pattern given above, repeat it as often as necessary to reach the desired number of targets and then remove all but the desired number of players. Removing a player does not change the distances between the remaining players and the targets, thus it is not against your rules. However, now some players have an advantage as the number of opponents around them is lower than for other players. Thus you might need to introduce more requirements to make it fair.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already said, there probably is no perfect solution meeting all of your requirements exactly without exorbitant calculation expenses.<sup>1</sup>

### Approach

My approach would be to replace the *same distance to all targets* requirement by a more flexible condition.

In the following example, I introduced a **heat** property for each cell, which should intuitively represent availability/proximity of targets.
It's calculated by adding up heat in relation to each target on the map.
The heat of in relation to a target is simply 1 divided by the distance (manhattan in my example) between them.
Maybe you'll want to use different implementations for the functions `heat` and `distance`.

### Player positioning

For distributing players, we do the following:

1. Keep a list off all cells, sorted by heat
2. Start at some cell (currently user-selected), find it in the sorted list and use its neighbors (with similar heat values) for player positions

This assures that heat values for player cells are always as close as possible.
An even better solution would be to search for a sequence of similar-as-possible heat values in the sorted list and use those.

### Example code

*Reload to have different target positions*

```js
var numPlayers = 4;
var numTargets = numPlayers;
var gridSize = numPlayers * 4;
var minDistance = 4;

var targetPositions = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numTargets; i++) {
 // TODO: Make sure targets don't get too close
  targetPositions[i] = randomPos();
}

var heatMap = [];
for (var i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
  heatMap[i] = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < gridSize; j++) {
    heatMap[i][j] = heat(i, j);
  }
}
printHeat();

function heat(x, y) {
  var result = 0;
  for (var i in targetPositions) {
    var pos = targetPositions[i];
    result += 1 / distance(x - pos.x, y - pos.y); // XXX: What about zero division?
  }
  return result;
}

function distance(l1, l2) {
  // manhattan distance
  return Math.abs(l1) + Math.abs(l2);
}

function randomPos() {
  return {
    x: random(gridSize),
    y: random(gridSize),
    toString: function() {
      return this.x + '/' + this.y
    }
  };

  function random(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
  }
}

function printHeat() {
  for (var i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
    var tr = $('<tr>');
    $('#heat').append(tr);
    for (var j = 0; j < gridSize; j++) {
      var heatVal = heatMap[i][j];
      var td = $('<td> ' + heatVal + ' </td>');
      if (heatVal > numTargets) // hack
        td.addClass('target');
      td.attr('data-x', i).attr('data-y', j);
      td.css('background-color', 'rgb(' + Math.floor(heatVal * 255) + ',160,80)');
      tr.append(td);
    }
  }
}

var cellsSorted = $('td').sort(function(a, b) {
  return numOfCell(a) > numOfCell(b);
}).toArray();
$('td').click(function() {
  $('.player').removeClass('player');
  var index = cellsSorted.indexOf(this);
  // TODO: Don't just search downwards, but in both directions with lowest difference
  for (var k = 0; k < numPlayers; k++) {
    var newIndex = index - k; // XXX Check against outOfBounds
    var cell = cellsSorted[newIndex];
    if (!validPlayerCell(cell)) {
      // skip one
      k--;
      index--;
      continue;
    }
    $(cell).addClass('player');
  }
});

function validPlayerCell(cell) {
  var otherItems = $('.player, .target').toArray();
  for (var i in otherItems) {
    var item = otherItems[i];
    var xa = parseInt($(cell).attr('data-x'));
    var ya = parseInt($(cell).attr('data-y'));
    var xb = parseInt($(item).attr('data-x'));
    var yb = parseInt($(item).attr('data-y'));
    if (distance(xa - xb, ya - yb) < minDistance)
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function numOfCell(c) {
  return parseFloat($(c).text());
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h2 {
  margin: 1ex 0;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #0af;
  padding: 0.5ex;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 10px;
  max-width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

td.target {
  border-color: #f80;
}

td.player {
  border-color: black;
}

td.player::after {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  content: "player here";
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Click a cell to distribute players</h2>
<table id="heat">

</table>
```

[**Same in JSFiddle to play around with variables**](https://jsfiddle.net/yaLz0vhp/17/)

### Open ends

This example has been stitched together quite quickly. You'll notice there are several open ends and uncovered corner cases. I just made it to outline my idea.

Not covered:

- Wrapping at edges: This probably only affects the `dist` function
- Distance among targets: They're just randomly thrown somewhere on the map
- Selection of positions just searches downward the `heat` list: This could be done smarter, e.g. shortest distance to original selected cell
- Automatic distribution of players (without clicking): You might just want to take a random one to start with

---

<sup>1</sup>*I mean, theoretically you could just try all possible variations and check if they're correct (if you have a large cluster in your backyard).*

Comment: The point about brute-force checking all possible variations is a good one. Your approach, as you mentioned, would need some tweaking to fit the requirements, but I like it!

Comment: This is a great idea! Suggestions The requirements say that diagonals = 1, so rather than manhattan distance, just `return Math.hypot(Math.abs(l1), Math.abs(l2));` Also, I think it's more fun with `var numTargets = Math.ceil(Math.random() * numPlayers * 1.3);`

Comment: @Josiah since the OP seems to be using a grid with cells, a formula more in keeping with his comment that distance is "the number of moves it takes to get from cell a to cell b," would be `max(abs(a.x - b.x), abs(a.y - b.y))` where `x,y` are the cell indexes in the grid, independent of cell size (I think that's without taking account of the wrap).

Comment: I'm accepting this answer since I really like this approach and I think I'm going to use a variant of it in the actual game. I awarded the rep bonus to גלעד ברקן's answer though since I believe it could actually meet the 'same distance to targets' requirement, which this one does not guarantee.

Comment: Unfortunately, while this algorithm guarantees some sort of 'equal average distance' to all targets, it does not care about equal access at all. Consider two targets and two players p1, p2. p1's target distances are 3 and 15, p2's target distances are 5 and 5. This algorithm considers both players optimally positioned, even though their target distances are completely different (computed on a torus using maximum distance as required by OP).

Answer (score 10):

Are you constrained to a flat plane? If you can move to 3D, then you can use the [Fibonacci Spiral](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/07/28/how-i-made-wine-glasses-from-sunflowers/) to generate an arbitrary number of equidistant points on a sphere. There's a really nice processing sketch of this at work at http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/41142 (with the code to go with it). The image below shows what it looks like. One benefit is that you automatically get the 'wrapping' included.

[image: Fibonacci Sphere]

If you have to stick to 2D, then you could try the above followed by a [spherical to planar projection](http://geokov.com/education/map-projection.aspx) that preserves the mapping. This may be a bit more complicated than you're looking for though...

Comment: Yes I am constrained to a 2D flat plane. Furthermore, distortion is inherent in any spherical to planar projection, so the distances between points would not be properly preserved. Even if I could use a sphere though, this doesn't address the player-to-target accessibility constraint.

Comment: This is a really creative idea +1

Comment: A sphere doesn't have the correct topology, he's pretty clear about it being equivalent to a torus.

Answer (score 5):

One intuitive solution that comes to mind is to divide the plane symmetrically according to the number of players, place one player and its target/s randomly and then reflect the placement symmetrically in the other sections. Bind the grid theoretically in a circle (or vice versa), then divide and reflect.

In a (theoretical) infinite-resolution grid, with its center as the center of a polar coordinate system, we could first place one player and it's targets (by the way, these can be placed anywhere on the grid and the symmetry will still hold), then to place the other `n - 1` players and target/s, increment the initial degree by `360° / n` each time, keeping the same radius. However, since your grid will have a practical size limit, you will need to somehow guarantee that the reflected cells exist on the grid, perhaps by a combination of restricting the initial generation and/or modifying the grid size/parity.

Something along the lines of:

```js
var numPlayers = 6;
var ts = 2;
var r = 8

function convertFromPolar(cs) {
  return [Math.round(cs[0] * Math.cos(cs[1] * Math.PI / 180)) + r
         ,Math.round(cs[0] * Math.sin(cs[1] * Math.PI / 180)) + r];
}

var first = [r,0];

var targets = [];
for (var i = 0; i < ts; i++) {
  var _first = first.slice();
  _first[0] = _first[0] - 4 - Math.round(Math.random() * 3);
  _first[1] = _first[1] + Math.round(Math.random() * 8);
  targets.push(_first);
}

var playerCells = [];
var targetCells = [];

for (var i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++) {
  playerCells.push(convertFromPolar(first).join('-'));
  first[1] = (first[1] + 360 / numPlayers) % 360;
  for (var j = 0; j < ts; j++) {
    targetCells.push(convertFromPolar(targets[j]).join('-'));
    targets[j][1] = (targets[j][1] + 360 / numPlayers) % 360;
  }
}

var cellSize = 20;
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

function Cell(x, y) {
  this.x = x * cellSize + cellSize / 2;
  this.y = y * cellSize + cellSize / 2;
  this.id = x + '-' + y;
  this.neighbors = [];
  this.type = null;
}

Cell.prototype.draw = function() {
  var color = '#ffffff';
  if (this.type === 'base') {
    color = '#0000ff';
  } else if (this.type === 'target') {
    color = '#ff0000';
  } else if (this.type === 'outOfBounds') {
    color = '#000000';
  }
  var d = cellSize / 2;
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(this.x - d, this.y - d, this.x + d, this.y + d);
  ctx.rect(this.x - d, this.y - d, this.x + d, this.y + d);
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.stroke();
};

var n = 24;
var m = 16;
canvas.width = n * cellSize + 6;
canvas.height = m * cellSize + 6;

var cellList = [];

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    var cell = new Cell(i, j);
    if (playerCells.indexOf(cell.id) > -1) {
      cell.type = 'base';
    } else if (targetCells.indexOf(cell.id) > -1) {
      cell.type = 'target';
    } else if (Math.pow(i - r,2) + Math.pow(j - r,2) > (r + 2)*(r + 2) ) {
      cell.type = 'outOfBounds';
    }
    cellList.push(cell);
  }
}

// Give each cell a list of it's neighbors so we know where things can move
for (var i = 0; i < cellList.length; i++) {
  var cell = cellList[i];
  var neighbors = [];

  // Get the cell indices around the current cell
  var cx = [cell.x - 1, cell.x, cell.x + 1];
  var cy = [cell.y - 1, cell.y, cell.y + 1];
  var ci, cj;

  for (ci = 0; ci < 3; ci++) {
    if (cx[ci] < 0) {
      cx[ci] = n - 1;
    }
    if (cx[ci] >= n) {
      cx[ci] = 0;
    }
    if (cy[ci] < 0) {
      cy[ci] = m - 1;
    }
    if (cy[ci] >= m) {
      cy[ci] = 0;
    }
  }
  for (ci = 0; ci < 3; ci++) {
    for (cj = 0; cj < 3; cj++) {
      // Skip the current node since we don't need to link it to itself
      if (cellList[n * ci + cj] === cell) {
        continue;
      }
      neighbors.push(cellList[n * ci + cj]);
    }
  }
}

drawGrid();

function drawGrid() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for (var i = 0; i < cellList.length; i++) {
    cellList[i].draw();
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you give more detail? Mathematically, how would you divide symmetrically and reflect on the grid? Can you guarantee the solution would work for each possible number of players?

Comment: @NanoWizard I added a rough combination of the reflection applied to your code (see my new snippet...didn't have time to shift the circle within the grid...). The boundaries of the wrap ought to be somewhere around `x^2 + y^2 <= (r + c)^2`. A variation would have the targets as an inner/outer circle in relation to players.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and give this solution the rep bonus, since with additional logic it appears as though it could fit all of the requirements as stated in the question. I'm going to label Cedric's as the accepted answer though because, although it doesn't strictly follow the player accessibility requirement, I like the additional unpredictability, so I think I will end up using a variant of that approach in the actual game. :)

Comment: @NanoWizard Thanks! Also glad you found an interesting approach for the game.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but can't you just make the grid as `N` copies of one random placement within bounds (`N` being the number of players)?

```
Define `p = (x,y)` as first player location

Make target/s randomly for `p` at least 4 cells away and
  within either a horizontal or vertical rectangular limit

Now define the grid as (N - 1) copies of the rectangle with space added 
  so as to make the regtangles form a square (if that's the final shape you want), 
  and observe minimum distance from other players
```

Since each rectangle is exactly the same, each player has equal access to the same number of targets.

Comment: Unfortunately while this would be easy to implement, it can only produce a 'square-like' result when `N` has factors that are close to each other. For example, in the case where N = 12, we can have 4 rows of 3 copied grid sections (since 4*3 = 12). If, however, we have 13 players (a prime number), the only way this solution meets all conditions is with 1 row (or column) of 13 copied sections, which isn't very square. I do think it would meet all other conditions though. You mention "space added so as to... form a square", but that won't ensure equal access by all players.

Comment: @NanoWizard odd configurations with more than one row might be workable considering wraparound (I'll think more on that) but of course one row can be made a square, just add appropriate space to the rectangle after the initial assignment so when it is multiplied you get a square.

Comment: that is technically true. The whole principle behind square-like though was to reduce the maximum required distance to travel across the map, and reduce the resource requirements of the grid, although I didn't mention either of those things specifically in the requirements.

Comment: @NanoWizard you might want to clarify in the question that "square-like" is referring to the final placement configuration of players and targets rather than the grid itself.

Answer (score 2):

I think the distance can't be exactly the same for every player in every combination, so you want to create a configuration that minimizes unfairnesses among players.

Do you know Hooke's law for strings? I imagine a situation in which all players and targets are connected with compressed strings that push proportionally to the current distance (with wraps). Let the system evolve from a particular initial configuration, even if it is not the fairest, but just an initial guess. The advantage is that you won't need to brute force it, you just leave it to adjust itself.

To rise the chances of convergence, you will need to implement friction/drag. I've been working with physics simulations, that is why I wrote this answer.

The disadvantage is: maybe it demands too much research effort before the implementation, which you were trying to avoid as you mentioned not being familiar with the said algorithms.